# Eclipse Kepler hangs when trying to debug Clojure project

Tags: eclipse, clojure, eclipse-kepler

Installed Eclipse-Kepler on a Windows 8 box. Clojure and Leiningen already installed. Installed Counterclockwise. Started up, created test Clojure project, ran without debugger, and ran successfully under debugger. Messed with it a bit more, was in and out of the debugger several times. After one debugging session got "an error" (yes, I know I should have written it down, but failed to do so. Take pity upon the soul of this poor sinner...). After that every debugging session I tried to start (using "Debug As...Clojure Application") failed to start, eventually timing out with a "Timed out waiting for REPL to start" error. Messed with it a while, uninstalled CCW, re-installed CCW - no change, REPL still refused to start under the debugger. Could *always* start a REPL by "sending" the text of the project file to the REPL using Ctrl-Alt-S. Finally deleted all of Kepler, re-installed, re-installed CCW, and could then debug again.

My questions: has anyone else encountered this, and is there a better workaround than blowing away the entire Eclipse install and re-extracting from the .zip?  I did do a check for updated versions of anything and nothing came up. Is this a Kepler issue, i.e. might this be more stable under Juno?

Comment: The error may be in the error log. Look at the Error Log view or the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: @greg-449 - many thanks. I already blew away the original install, reinstalled, etc, but I'll keep this in mind if/when it occurs again.